# How can I print from Galaxy Note 2 via Wifi -> Desktop ->USB-HP-Printer

Tags: printing, wifi-transfer, cellular

I have a Galaxy Note 2 which I connect to local wifi router. To the same router the Windows-based PC is connected to which in turn connected HP-printer (4500, has no BT).

The question is how can I print from the Galaxy on the Printer connected to Desktop?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=hp%20printer%20app%20wireless&hl=en